PROTOCOL_ERROR in libcontainerd docker module resulting to huge syslog and daemon.log files
I've recently installed docker in my VPS (Debian). The docker currently have 2 running containers : Node.Js app and MySQL.
Today I got an error message from my app saying that there's no free space in /var.
Running ls -lSh /var/log gives :
-rw-r-----  1 root adm              23G Aug  8 13:01 syslog.1
-rw-r-----  1 root adm              23G Aug  8 13:01 daemon.log.1

And running tail -f /var/log/syslog.1 gives a repeating messages:
Aug  8 12:41:30 vmi1856487 dockerd[542]: time="2024-08-08T12:41:30.156088825+02:00" level=info msg="Waiting for containerd to be ready to restart event processing" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby
Aug  8 12:41:30 vmi1856487 dockerd[542]: time="2024-08-08T12:41:30.156332291+02:00" level=error msg="Failed to get event" error="rpc error: code = Internal desc = stream terminated by RST_STREAM with error code: PROTOCOL_ERROR" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby

I've tried doing some research on how to fix this error but no luck. Can anyone help me how to fix this error or should I reinstall docker ?

The repeated PROTOCOL_ERROR messages are filling up your log files, causing them to become extremely large and consuming all the free space in /var.
First, you need to free up space so you can work on fixing the underlying issue:
sudo truncate -s 0 /var/log/syslog.1
sudo truncate -s 0 /var/log/daemon.log.1

After truncating the logs, restart Docker to stop the log files from continuing to fill up:
sudo systemctl restart docker

Now that you have some breathing room, look into the root cause of the issue:
Make sure that both Docker and containerd are up to date. An incompatibility between versions could be causing the issue.
docker --version
containerd --version

Check if the logs within the containers are producing any errors that might help diagnose the issue. You can view logs for a specific container using:
docker logs <container_id>

Also, you can limit the size of your log files by configuring the logging options in Docker. Add the following to your /etc/docker/daemon.json to rotate the logs and prevent them from growing indefinitely:
{
  "log-driver": "json-file",
  "log-opts": {
    "max-size": "10m",
    "max-file": "3"
  }
}

If the error persists and there seems to be no clear fix, reinstalling Docker might help.
sudo systemctl stop docker
sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io containerd runc
sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io

Good luck!

Thank you for your response! I'll give it a try before reinstalling Docker

I tried all of the above but end up reinstalling docker. That solved the issue for now.
